# Creating Dynamic Web Page

Tags: asp.net, dynamically-generated, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to create a dynamic web page from a template.Then i want to create a menu item from it.

I am creating the page(testtest.aspx for example) and everything works fine but the created page doesn't include in project so i can't reach it because the page is not compiling.How can i do this programmatically ?

**This is the code that generates the page**

[image: http://imgur.com/oljO41v]

**When i try to access the testest.aspx page i get this error:**

[image: http://imgur.com/SX6lJWh]

**How can i solve this ? Thank you very much**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for loading aspx pages from a location other than file-system. ASP.Net has built-in mechanism for doing that using providers: `VirtualPathProvider`.

Details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx

This will point you in the right direction: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441

Comment: Actually i am creating the page inside of the project.I am not trying to access from another location.Everything is in the file system.When i open a new  web page in visual studio the code is working properly but when i try to use this code in project section in visual studio the code is not working.

Comment: It seems that your project is a WAP instead of Website. You will have to change the @Page directive: instead of `CodeBehind=`, it will be `CodeFile`. And also you will have to remove the namespace from `Inherits=`.